# How can I make URLQueryItem with large bracket ([])?

Tags: swift, urlcomponents

I need to make a URL with query parameter with large bracket.
this is the example.

```
https://samlpe.com/detail?item_code[]=smtwGBArkp3ByfrLK3KfxdoX
```

I trying to use URLComponents and URLQueryItem. but URLQueryItem don't take array (`["code"]` in below) as a value.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: URL(string: "https://samlpe.com/detail")!,
                                                        resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "item_code", value: ["code"])]
```

Does anybody hove idea for that?

Comment: @Alexander
I see, yes, it is working. Thanks!.

Comment: I made my comment into an answer that you can vote on and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` has no special meaning. This is just:

```
URLQueryItem(name: "item_code[]", value: "smtwGBArkp3ByfrLK3KfxdoX")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander mentioned

```
URLQueryItem(name: "item_code[]", value: "smtwGBArkp3ByfrLK3KfxdoX")
```

was enough for this.